# Changing variables in a forked process from outside that fork?

Tags: shell, scripting

In theory with this block, you should only see "running..." once(or less), but in practice, it repeats until it's manually killed. How do I change the value of x inside the forked process to false from outside the forked process after the function "start" has been called?

```
export x=true
start() {
while [ $x == true ]; do
    echo running...
    sleep 1
done
}

start &
x=false
```

Comment: In this case, the correct theory agrees with practice.

Comment: Well I hate to disagree but that's not what happens at all. It repeats "running..." over and over until it's manually killed. I encourage you to test it.

Comment: @anonymouse: your theory is wrong. You'd get that behavior (assuming proper synchronization) from threads, not forked processes. You'll need something else than the environment for communication (pipes/signals/files/...)

Comment: The shell doesn't ordinarily share variables between processes. In ksh, you can write extensions in C code that can do arbitrary things, including interprocess communication, when setting or getting variables. In bash, you can use the bashdb debugger to alter variables in another process. But the easiest way to communicate between two shell processes is to have them read and write a common file.

Comment: Yeah I'll probably just have it create and execute a file containing the code then pkill and delete that file when it's supposed to stop the loop.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick No need to write C code, you can do that with ksh scripting.

Comment: @jlliagre Thanks. I was thinking that C code (along with the discipline functions) would be better suited to do the IPC, but your solution of reading and writing a file directly in the discipline functions is neater.

Answer (score 3):

The simple solution here to use some kind of interprocess communication to tell the target process to make the change. For example, you could use signals:

```
#!/bin/sh

export x=true
start() {
trap x=false USR1
while [ $x = "true" ]; do
    echo running...
    sleep 1
done
}

start &
sleep 5
kill -USR1 $!
wait
```

produces this output:

```
$ ./testit.sh
running...
running...
running...
running...
running...
$
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `ksh93`, you can use discipline functions to implement shared variables (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726293/environment-variables-to-be-used-across-multiple-korn-ksh93-shell-scripts-get )

Alternatively, you might use `fish` which implements this feature through a daemon: [fishd](http://linux.die.net/man/1/fishd).